# Sumando elementos de una lista Haskell

Tags: haskell

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de programación en Haskell, en el cual doy unos valores en una lista por ejemplo [1, 2, 2, 3, 4] y debe quedar de la siguiente forma [1, 4, 3, 4]. Hasta ahí el programa me funciona sin problemas con el siguiente código:

```
sustituirSumando [x,y] 
              | x==y = [x+y]
              | otherwise = [x,y]
sustituirSumando [x,y,z] 
              | x==y = [x+y,z]   
              | y==z = [x,y+z]
              |otherwise = [x,y,z] 
sustituirSumando (x:y:xs) 
               | x==y = (x+y) : sustituirSumando (xs)                
               | otherwise = x: sustituirSumando (y:xs)
```

Donde no sé cómo proceder es en el siguiente supuesto ejemplo [1, 2, 2, 4, 5] aquí la lista debería quedar de la siguiente forma [1, 8, 5] pero en mi código queda [1, 4, 4, 5]. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la recursión, tienes que añadir el sumando a la lista de nuevo. Algo así:

```
sustituirSumando :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
sustituirSumando [] = []
sustituirSumando [x] = [x]
sustituirSumando (x:y:xs) | x==y      = sustituirSumando (x+y:xs)
                          | otherwise = x:sustituirSumando (y:xs)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esto queda solucionado!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Puede crear una funcion que recibe dos listas de `int` como entradas y devuelve una lista de `int`.
Necesitamos dos entradas para que podemos usar recursion en la funcion.

```hs
suma1 :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

La primera entrada es una lista que guarda el resultado de cada iteracion. En el primer iteracion, la primera lista debe estar vacia (`[]`).
La segunda entrada es el resto de la lista que no se ha procesado en la funcion.

Hacemos la operacion paso por paso.
En cada iteracion, probamos si el ultimo elemento de la primera lista esta igual al primer elemento de la segunda lista.
El iteracion se termina cuando no hay ninguno elemento existe en la segunda lista.

Aqui utilizamos las funciones `init` y `last` para obtener partes especificas de una lista.

**Codigo:**

```hs
suma1 :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
suma1 [] [] = []
suma1 [] [a] = [a]
suma1 [] (y:ys) = suma1 [y] ys
suma1 x (y:ys) =
   if ys == []
   then
      if last x == y 
      then init x ++ [(last x) + y] 
      else x ++ [y]
   else
      if last x == y 
      then suma1 (init x ++ [(last x) + y]) ys 
      else suma1 (x ++[y]) ys
```

**Ejemplo:**

Si ejecutar `suma1 [] [1, 2, 2, 4, 5]`, el operacion es:

```
Primera Lista  |  Segunda Lista
-------------------------------------
     []            [1,2,2,4,5]
     [1]           [2,2,4,5]
     [1,2]         [2,4,5] -> hacer adicion
     [1,4]         [4,5] -> hacer adicion
     [1,8]         [5]
     [1,8,5]       []  -> la funcion termina
```

---

Si no quiere entrar una lista vacia como argumento, puede llamar `suma1` desde otra funcion:

```hs
sustituirSumando :: [Int] -> [Int]
sustituirSumando x = suma1 [] x
```